# why two different owner for posix_getpwuid(fileowner($file)) within same directory, what does it mean?

Tags: php, file-io

I have a shared virtual Linux hosting with a hosting company and I know to use only CPANEL and I dont know to use CLI. Recent migration to PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3.2 by host is throwing permission denied error for writing into a file while using file_put_contents in a directory. So I thought to try few debug things in my capacity

```
// Assume my file is 
// here /home/myhostaccount/public_html/mytest where mytest is 755
// Assume migrated.log exists in the above directory and migrated.log is 644

$file1 = "migrated.log" // this is migrated file which is denied write
$file2 = "dummytest.log"    // this file I created for debug, it allows write

writeme($file1,"This file existed before in 5.2 and was writeable, but fails to do a write after migration  "); 
  // permission denied error failed to write BUT works if file forced to 646

writeme($file2,"This is created file by Me for Debugging ");    
  // works - writes just for the default 644

function writeme($file ,$data) {
  $result = file_put_contents($file , $data, LOCK_EX);
  if ($result === false) {
    echo "failed to write to $file";  echo "<br/>";
   }else{
    echo "successfully written $result bytes to $file <br/>";
  } 
 }
```

Next I thought I would check the fileowner and hence

```
 print_r(posix_getpwuid(fileowner($file1)));
 echo "<br/><br/>";
 print_r(posix_getpwuid(fileowner($file2)));
```

I get output as

```
Array ( [name] => myhostaccount [passwd] => x [uid] => 1083 [gid] => 1083 [gecos] => [dir] => /home/myhostaccount [shell] => /bin/bash ) 

Array ( [name] => nobody [passwd] => x [uid] => 99 [gid] => 99 [gecos] => Nobody [dir] => / [shell] => /sbin/nologin )
```

In first place I am not a good admin to understand this full output, but I surprised why two different things

My question are

a) why a file which is in same directory would run as different owner 1) myhostaccount 2) nobody

b) why nobody is able to do a successful write with 644 while myhostaccount is failing but able to write only with 646

c) where is the problem ? on my side ....or... on the hosting side

d) If it has to be fix on my side what I should do or if it is with them what I should ask them to do

Kindly help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The **only** reason for this can be, that one of the files had already existed and the other one was *created* by PHP

Comment: Is it possible and right to change ownwer of file1(myhostaccount) like file2(nobody). How do I resolve it any pointers would be great help. regards

Comment: `Is it possible and right to change ownwer of file1` .. can you explain?